# Get live width of the element

Tags: jquery

I have an empty h2 element with `width=0`. Afterwards I put some content in the h2 with JavaScript. How can I get the new width of the h2 element?

Before: `<h2></h2>`, then I do `$('h2').html('hello');`, then i have: `<h2>hello</h2>`.

Comment: The same way you get it before you insert the content.

Comment: nominating for re-opening because the difference from the duplicate is that it deals with a header element with the width set statically, while the proposed duplicate deals with an element with no static width set.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) is how you get the live width of an element.

Your bigger problem is that setting a block level element's width statically, **does not allow it to expand to fit content**.  If you set the css of that h2 to `overflow:hidden` you will probably see what I mean.

Header tags by default fill the available width of the parent even when empty.

Comment: I'm getting 0, when I do $('h2').width()